# How to have numbers written out as text like fmtcount does, but one word per number?

Tags: formatting

using the package `fmtcount`, a simple `\numberstringnum{1234}` writes out as *onethousandtwohundred and thirty-four*. I couldn't find a way to have it written as *one* *two* *three* *four* except for loads of '\numberstringnum{}' commands.

Which package/extension am I missing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just define a loop to format each character separately.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fmtcount}
\newcommand\numberloop{}
% \expandafter to allow \newcommand\numbers{3456} \numberseq{\numbers}
\newcommand\numberseq[1]{\expandafter\numberloop#1\end}
\def\numberloop#1#2\end{%
   \numberstringnum{#1}\ifx\relax#2\relax\else\space\numberloop#2\end\fi}
\begin{document}
\numberseq{9}\\
\numberseq{1234}

\newcommand\numbers{3456}
\numberseq{\numbers}
\end{document}
```